# mysql launch fails after upgrade to 5.7.11

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

After upgrading a Mac to OS X 10.11.3, mysql was gone, so I downloaded and installed 5.7.11. It installed as usual but fails to launch with;

(com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[1560]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

in the system log. It respawns and fails repeatedly!

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Locate the mysql error log and check the errors in there.

Comment: That's `mysqld.err`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql.local.err  Thank you so much @Rick James. The log showed that some of the my.cnf values were failing, about 5 IIRC!  WTF? I expect there were old values from the previous install which are no longer valid.

After I commented them out, the server started up fine.